# In dockerfile after create or copy file or directory in RUN statement it not/doesn't exists

Tags: laravel, docker, file-io, composer-php, dockerfile

I face following problem ilustrated by below dockerfile:

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN touch test.txt

CMD while true; do sleep 1000; done
```

After run above docker as *project* container and login to it by

```
docker exec -it project /bin/bash
```

We will si that '/var/www/html/test.txt' not exist.

This is bigger problem especially if we instead of creating one file wanna for instance use composer in php laravel project:

```
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY ./composer.json .
COPY ./composer.lock .
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader
```

Then we sadly discover than **vendor**-s directory doesnt exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make research and found out that cause of problem is that dockerfile of base image **richarvey/nginx-php-fpm** at the bottom have instruction:

```
VOLUME /var/www/html
```

which 'block' access to volume inside child container in RUN statements. This problem is connected wit this [topic on github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3639#issuecomment-48154253)

So what to do if our base image use **VOLUME** statement?

We can use following workaround (by using temporary directory and **mv** command in **CMD** statement):

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm

WORKDIR /tmp/project

RUN touch test.txt

WORKDIR /var/www/html

CMD mv /tmp/project/* /var/www/html/ &&\
    while true; do sleep 1000; done
```

So for PHP project with composer it will look for instance like this:

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm

WORKDIR /tmp/project

# cache vendors lib in separate docker layer
COPY ./composer.json .
COPY ./composer.lock .
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader

# process project code
ADD . .
RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize &&\
    composer run-script post-install-cmd &&\
    php artisan key:generate &&\
    ...

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# we use mv twice to move hidden files
CMD mv /tmp/ocenomat/* /var/www/html/ &&\
    mv /tmp/ocenomat/.* /var/www/html/ ; fi &&\
    ...
```

Comment: @brunocascio - thank's - very interesting dockerfile for nginx-php-fpm without VOLUME statement :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes, VOLUME on Dockerfile actually is a very bad idea. Today exists just for retro compatibility but seriously, is not recommended because, on each new container creation, a new volume is created then a lot of dangling volumes are stored.

Comment: If you need share data across containers, you could use `named volumes`.